# djangorestframework-simplejwt not working

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm following a Udemy Course with user administration and I need to install this

```
pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

After its installed, I need to add this to settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (   
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```

But its gives me this error

```
ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'.
```

So far I haven't been been able to find anything on google

Answer (score 1):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    ...
]
```

It should be added in INSTALLED_APPS

Source: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html